# How to improve the cognitive accuracy of a chat bot that is created on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

How can we optimize the domain-specific accuracy of a chat bot that gives cognitively reply to the end user? Or, how can we train our bots to make its context full to reply for a specific set of questions on Bluemix?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? How is your chatbot deployed? What Bluemix services is it using? Provide the context of your app, environment, etc., so that you can receive a useful answer.

Comment: i want to use whatson conversation service for academic purpose where pupils ask to chatbot and get accurate answers. i had just try conversation service in sandbox available on official website.

Answer (score 1):

The Watson conversation service uses the same underlying technology for "Intents" that is used in [Natural Language Classifier](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/) (NLC).

So you need a minimum of 5 questions per intent to train. Over 10 questions per intent is recommended.

After classifying I recommend to take 10-20% out (depending on number of questions), which you can use to test your system. You don't use them to train, only test.

**To get best results**

Make sure that your questions are representative of the end user. This is not what you think the end user will ask, but actual questions from the end user. This can either be achieved by reviewing support/customer logs, or targeted surveys.

Using questions created by yourself or manufactured will work well if the people who created them, test the system. For others it will not perform as well.

There are other factors as well, but this is normally the first biggest killer to accuracy.